# Types for observable

Tags: rxjs

I would like to have an type for my observable (just for learning purposes). How can I do it for the follwoing lines of code? I get compiler errors and don't understand them.

```
type Color = "white" | "green" | "red" | "blue";
type Logo = "fish" | "dog" | "bird" | "cow";

const color$ = new Subject<Color>();
const logo$ = new Subject<Logo>();

const observabl1:<Subject<Color>, Subject<Logo>> = combineLatest([color$, logo$]);

observabl1.subscribe(([color, logo]) =>
  console.log(`${color} ${logo}`)
);
```

and

```
const observable2$:Observable<string> = from(["white", "green", "red", "blue"]);
```

[image]

**Update: I found the error. I imported import { Observable } from 'rx'; Changing it to import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; fixed the problem**

Comment: You won't learn anything by using any. That out of the way, what did you try? What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

> I get compiler errors and don't understand them

Kindly provide the errors you want to discuss.

> const observabl1:<Subject, Subject> = combineLatest([color$, logo$]);

combineLatest provides a stream with an array of the data.

`const observabl1: Observable<[Color, logo]> = combineLatest([color$, logo$]);`